# Existing summation approach for computation of combination?

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Recently, I bumped into an interesting approach to alternately calculate the combinations. But I am not sure if there is such theory already existing for generic combinations with arbitrary factorials.

Say, now we are going to evaluate $\binom{N}{p}$ with $p=3$. Instead of factorials, the summation of products can be used.
$$\binom{N}{3}=\frac{N!}{(N-3)!3!}=\sum_{i=1}^N(i-1)(N-i)$$
which can be readily proved as
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N(i-1)(N-i)&=-N^2+(N+1)\sum_{i=1}^Ni-\sum_{i=1}^Ni^2\\
&=-N^2+(N+1)\frac{N(N+1)}{2}-\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}\\
&=N\frac{3(N+1)^2-6N-(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}\\
&=\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{6}.
\end{align}

Otherwise, this can be thought in this way. We need to select three numbers from $1,2,\ldots,N$. So we just need to sum up all the cases from our choices. If we step from the first ($i=1$) to the last ($i=N$) and the other two are just the left and right, so the smaller numbers have $i-1$ possibilities, and the larger ones $N-i$ which then arrives $(i-1)(N-i)$ cases for each $i$. The sum of these steps are just exactly what we usually call $\binom{N}{3}$.

Comment: +1 : impressive, both in the Algebra, and the Combinatoric intuition.

Comment: Indeed, you've shown that $\displaystyle \binom N3 = \sum_{i=1}^N \binom{i-1}1 \binom{N-i}1$, and the same proof shows that $\displaystyle \binom Np = \sum_{i=1}^N \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{N-i}{p-k-1}$ for any $0\le k\le p-1$.

Comment: @GregMartin I think you meant $p-k$ instead of $p-k-1$.

Comment: And $1 \le k \le p$.