# Is there a general formula for the sum of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I am learning statistics, and I'm doing some stuff with combinations. Some of the questions I have seen have answers which are equal to a sum of combinations. It made me wonder, is there a formula for the sum of combinations, i.e. $$\sum_{k=i}^{j}{n \choose k}$$ for $0\le i \le j \le n$?

I have looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299273/sum-of-combinations-of-n-taken-k-where-k-is-from-n-to-n-21) which calculates the results: 
$$\sum_{k=(n+1)/2}^n \dbinom{n}k = 2^{n-1}, \  \text{for odd} \ n$$ and $$\sum_{k=n/2+1}^n \dbinom{n}k = 2^{n-1} - \dfrac12 \dbinom{n}{n/2}, \ \text{for even} \ n  $$

Although, using Pascal's triangle, one could see that the result for odd n would just be the sum of the row / 2 = $2^n - 1$. Can't see an intuitive way to figure it out for even $n$ though.

I also know that ${n \choose 0} = {n \choose n} = 1 $

Comment: Alas, there is no simple formula for the general partial sum of a row of Pascal'e triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such closed formula.

> A corresponding statement can be found for instance in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/3_Theory/Mathematics/Concrete%20Mathematics.pdf)*
> by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik. See formula (5.17) where we can read

> - How about the simpler partial sum,
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{k\leq m}\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{m}\tag{5.17}
>   \end{align*}
>   ... But no; there is no closed form for the partial sum of a row of Pascal's triangle.